# Ssrs reporting to default select parameter 2 when some value in parameter 1 is selected

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, default-value

In my report I have `6 parameters`. I want `parameter 2` to by default select all when I choose some option in `parameter 1` and all other parameters stay blank. If I choose `parameter 3`, then `parameter 4` should by default select all. I have tried everything and there is some `null problem` in it.

Comment: Please share some of the code that you have tried so we may help you

Comment: I just want to know like how can we do that generally. Like selecting  a value in parameter one which is a column name. And the parameter 2 is basically the entries inside that column. I want all the options to get default selected. Likeways i have 6 parameter where 2 depends on 1, and 4 depends on what i choose in 3. But i want the 2 and 4 to get automatically select all once i choose something in 1 and 3. I know i am littile confusing. Hope somebody can catchup.. help pls

Comment: The only way this will work is to use Multi select, cascading parameters and then setting the default parameters based on the previous parameter. what is your datasource? SQL server? Just create multiple datasets for each parameter and make each one dependent on the previous. You can then specify a case statement to populate the parameter defaults based on previous parameter selections.